# django permissions instead of groups

Tags: django, templates, permissions, tags, visibility

We have multiple positions in the hierarchy of the company : such as director of sales, salesperson, restaurant director and let say maitre d'hotel,

however if we have a follow up or a memo some might be a good fit for the whole staff to see but if the memo concern the pricing strategy of a particular quote, we don't want the maitre d'hotel to see this particular follow up, or quote, or detail in the dashboards

as of now I understand that the permission system allow us to briefly avoid that tier be able to edit or delete a particular model instance from the database :

should I do a attribute level of permissions such as writing a model with level 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 (permissions ) and attribute one to each user and add template tags that will display a different html page or is there a better way to do it,

thanks

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to utilise groups? It seems it would fit quite well in this scenario

Comment: @Lewis it is because it will be a field that i will add directly to a particular comment it might not be a matter of CRUD, just a matter of display if you know what I mean